# Windows Phone BackgroundTransferService Max (Pending)Queue Size

Tags: file-upload, download, windows-phone, background-transfer

Based on the msdn statement, windows phone can have a maximum of 25 outbound background transfers per application.I tried the same and got only 5 transfers in the queue.
Please clarify the difference between the statement and practical execution.

Comment: Are you getting an exception when you try to add 6 `BackgroundTransferRequest` at one time?

Comment: @Neil Turner ,                                                  No.After reaching 5 outbound transfers in queue , getting an alert message which says the maximum number of transfers for the application has been reached.

Comment: My reading is that queue can have a max. of 25 items, only 5 active at a time - the rest would be marked as 'Completed', and should be removed before more are added.

Comment: If only 5 active transfers are allowed , then there may be a need to add additional check for each transfer to verify the completion of file receiving/sending process.Anyway thank you for your help my friend.